# How to upload Angular JS npm (UI) artifacts to nexus 2 using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nexus, sonatype

How to upload Angular JS artifacts to nexus 2.14.5 using Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. Please see https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6857 for more information, we implemented Scoped support which would have been I think the real obstacle for uploading Angular components in Nexus Repo 2.

I myself haven't done this using Jenkins, but you should be able to run `npm publish` on a package and upload it. Take a look [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Node+Packaged+Modules+and+npm+Registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-PublishingnpmPackages) for more info on how to configure npm and Nexus Repo 2.

Hope this helps!